# Add MEMBER to username when joined

Tags: discord.js

I am trying making my bot change the nickname to **Member** when someone joins but I have no idea how to make that... If someone could help

EXAMPLE:

If a member named Noob join the bot will change it name to: **[Member] Noob**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are expected to do/show some attempts and research before asking on Stack Overflow. Here are the docs for [GuildMember#setNickname()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname)

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for `guildMemberAdd` and use `.setNickname` to update the nickname.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   member.setNickname('[Member] ' + member.displayName);
});
```

Comment: Nice I found out this
// on member on event
<client>.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // set the members nickname
  member.setNickname("[Member] " + member.username);
});
But the member username return undefined